# how can i to make @blur event work properly - Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, nuxt.js, blur

I am trying to trigger a function that validates an input field when it loses focus using nuxtjs. When I focus out of the input field, the function isn't triggered but gets triggered when I focus in and start typing in another or the same input field.

```html
<div class="control">
  <input class="input" type="text" ref="email" @blur="validateMail()" v-model="email_p" name="email" />
</div>
```

this is the function call

```js
 methods: {
        validateMail(){
            let value = this.$refs.email.value
            let mailformat = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

            if (value.match(mailformat)) {
                //validation passed
            } else {
                this.msg.email = 'Enter a valid email';
            }
        },
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not triggered? Tried a `console.log`? Checked the event in the Vue devtools? Mind sharing a [repro]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work fine

```html
<template>
  <div class="control">
    <input
      ref="email"
      v-model="email_p"
      class="input"
      type="text"
      name="email"
      @blur="validateMail"
    />
    message: {{ msg.email }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email_p: '',
      msg: {
        email: '',
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validateMail(value) {
      const mailformat =
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

      if (value.target.value.match(mailformat)) {
        // validation passed
      } else {
        this.msg.email = 'Enter a valid email'
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

You don't need to use `$refs` to access the element, you can access the event directly.
If you want to get the `value` via `$refs`, you would need to wait for a full [`tick` to trigger](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick), to get the actual new value. Hence use the `event` passed by `@blur`, simpler, cleaner and less messy.

Also, `value.target.value` is important because it's receiving an event and not the HTML element itself.

PS: the event can also be written as `@blur="validateMail($event)"` if you want to be more explicit but it's not mandatory (it's passing it by itself already).

Comment: this hasn't solved the problem, please suggest further solutions

Comment: @payose I've tried it locally with the code you've provided me. What is not working? Are you sure you took all my code without a typo?

Comment: I just checked again and it works. i overlooked the ```msg: []``` which i had in my code, but on changing it to yours which is  ```msg: {
        email: '',
      },```  it works fine. Please can you explain to me why your methods works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @payose my method works because it's using the direct value of the event. It doesn't rely on the DOM and it's available without waiting for the next tick. Your example was based on getting the value after the VDOM is flushed.